# Append data to a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been trying to create a nested dictionary I guess there is something about dictionaries I'm missing. I succeeded in created the values and keys on my console but was getting errors when I tried to append it. It kept giving me the last value in my dictionary. Please what I'm I doing wrong?

```
u= [(2, 'errorid 4'), (1, 'errorid 4260'), (6, 'errorid 7'), (75, 'errorid 0'),
    (1, 'errorid 14'), (4, 'errorid 4b07')]
v=['Frequency', 'Item']

data ={}
dicts ={}

for i,con in enumerate(u):
    con = list(con)
    for m,n in enumerate(con):
        dicts[v[m]]=n
    print(dicts)
    data[i+1]=dicts
```

The output on the console for dicts was correct, but when I tried to nest it is was not working:

```
{'Frequency': 2, 'Item': 'errorid 4'}
{'Frequency': 1, 'Item': 'errorid 4260'}
{'Frequency': 6, 'Item': 'errorid 7'}
{'Frequency': 75, 'Item': 'errorid 0'}
{'Frequency': 1, 'Item': 'errorid 14'}
{'Frequency': 4, 'Item': 'errorid 4b07'}
```

Output should look like this:

```
data = {1: {'Frequency': 2, 'Item': 'errorid 4'},
        2: {'Frequency': 1, 'Item': 'errorid 4260'},
        3: {'Frequency': 6, 'Item': 'errorid 7'}
        4: {.... }
```

Comment: You are using the adding the same reference to `dicts` over and over so when you modify it, you modify them all. Try defining `dicts` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = {i + 1: {p: q for p, q in zip(v, x)} for i, x in enumerate(u)}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'Frequency': 2, 'Item': 'errorid 4'}, 2: {'Frequency': 1, 'Item': 'errorid 4260'},
 3: {'Frequency': 6, 'Item': 'errorid 7'}, 4: {'Frequency': 75, 'Item': 'errorid 0'}, 
 5: {'Frequency': 1, 'Item': 'errorid 14'}, 6: {'Frequency': 4, 'Item': 'errorid 4b07'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` dictionary consists of a bunch of copies of the same dictionary (`dicts`), which you keep overwriting.  Every time you change the values in `dicts` you're implicitly changing the value for all the entries in `data` simultaneously.

The comprehension in Jean-Claude's answer will build a new dict for each item, avoiding this problem.